# Using Pull Subscription for Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have Two GCP Projects .

1. One Project contain Publisher Topic.
2. Second Project is having Subscription to First Project Topic.

**Issue**: I want to Trigger a Cloud Function when Subscriber Receive the Message.
can anyone help me we that.

I tried to use Cloud function Trigger where only topic of that Project(Second Project) are listed that is not the solution.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you intend to interact between these two projects? it may need a more extensive sollution

Comment: I created a Service Account in Second Project (Subscriber one) and assigned a Pubub Subscriber and pubSub Viewer Role.                                                                                 In First Project (Topic one) i use same Service Account with Pubsub Pubilsher and Viewr  Role.

Comment: Are you trying to do any additional processing in your subscriber code, other than triggering the Cloud Function? If all you want to do is trigger the Cloud Function, you can use an HTTP-triggered Cloud Function with an HTTP Push subscription as Guillaume described in his answer. Otherwise, you can use an HTTP-triggered Cloud Function and issue the HTTP request yourself from your subscriber code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to use a [PubSub triggered Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub), the PubSub topic **must** be in the same project as the Cloud Functions.

However, you have a workaround, you can create an [HTTP triggered Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) and to create an [HTTP Push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) on your PubSub topic (in the project that you want). Like that, anytime that a message is published in PubSub topic, the push subscription send it to Cloud Functions.

---

Your title mention "Pull" subscription. But when you create a PubSub triggered Cloud Functions, you don't create a pull subscription, but also a push subscription. Have a look to your PubSub subscription after a PubSub triggered Cloud Functions, you will see something like that:

[image]

Still push. No difference!